# How to login a web page which is loaded by jquery with perl module WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, web, authentication

I'm using the WWW::Mechanize module to login a web site. but i found the login page(main.html) is loaded by a jquery in the index.html.

If i use the get method, i can only get the index.html, but not the main.html(the actuall login page)

Do you guys have any idea on how to implement the code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $outfile = "out.html";
my $url = "https://XXXXX.mysite.com";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
               form_number => 3,
               fields      => {
                   username    => 'mungo',
                   password    => 'lost-and-alone',
               }
           );
```

### Error:

Error GETing https://XXXXX.mysite.com: Can't connect to XXXXX.mysite.com：443 at getweb.pl line 10.

Comment: You'll need to make sense of the JavaScript on perl side. Have you given http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-JavaScript-0.008a/lib/WWW/Scripter/Plugin/JavaScript.pm a try? A shot in the dark from me; no real experience with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used it but get below errors, any idea about this? ReferenceError: The variable JSON has not been declared at XXXXX.mysite.com/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4. ReferenceError: The variable jQuery has not been declared at XXXXX.mysite.com/js/jquery.upload-1.0.2.js,

Comment: Sorry James, I'm out of my depth here.

Answer (score 0):

WWW::Mechanize does not run JavaScript.

(See the [WWW::Mechanize FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript) for more details.)

Ideally the site would provide a non-JS way to log in.  But since it doesn't, try loading main.html directly and submitting the login form that it provides.